# Using sensor data from an android project in a regular java project

Tags: android

I have an android project that gets acceleration values using the accelerometer.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
float x,y; 
x = event.values[0];
y = event.values[1];
}
```

I also have a regular java project that draws a point at a given location (x,y) using java swing.

I want that location to be some manipulation of the x, y acceleration values I get from the android project. Like, onSensorChanged should call a method in the regular java project that draws the dot and pass the x, y values. So ultimately, the swing code will track the movement of the phone. But that's not the important part. I just want to know how I would connect an android project to a regular project that uses swing.
Probably didn't express my intention well, but if anybody gets what I'm trying to do, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect your Android Application with another Application that's running on a PC, you need a Socket connection between these 2 devices. One (maybe the Android Phone) should open a Port, and the PC then connects to the Phones IP:Port. Your Phone should listen to these connections and should write x,y to the connection. The PC can read it and can draw it in a Graphic.

For the Server you need the Java class SocketServer and for the Client the class Socket.

You can find some examples here: http://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to do that in the future. But for now, is it possible to do it while the phone is connected to the computer by the USB cable?

Comment: This is much more complicated. Use Sockets over TCP and you're on the right way ;-)

On the Server: Create a SocketServer, accept incomming connections, create a PrintWriter for the socket outputstream and write the data you want to transmit.

On the Client: Create a Socket to the server and read data if available.